# How to pass a query to FirestoreRecyclerOptions?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using a FirestoreRecyclerAdapter to display my items in a recyclerView.
Using searchView, i am able to create a query:

```
querySearch = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                   .collection("App").document(" " + userID).collection("reminders")
                   .startAt("title", newText)
                   .endAt("title", newText+"\uf8ff");
```

My question is, how can I pass the query to FirestoreRecyclerOptions so that my recyclerView displays what I am searching for?

(I'm using Cloud Firestore)

EDIT: here is my updated code

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


           querySearch = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                   .collection("App").document(" " + userID).collection("reminders")
                   .orderBy(newText);


           FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Reminder> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Reminder>()
                   .setQuery(querySearch, Reminder.class)
                   .build();


           //create new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter:
           adapterSearch = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Reminder, ReminderHolder>(options) {
               @Override
               public void onBindViewHolder(final ReminderHolder holder, int position, final Reminder model) {

                   holder.bind(model);
                   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View view) {

                           openEditPopup();

                           DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                           docID = snapshot.getId();

                       }
                   });
               }

               @Override
               public ReminderHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int i) {
                   View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_beta, group, false); //todo use beta item layout
                   return new ReminderHolder(view);
               }
           };

           recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterSearch);
           adapterSearch.startListening(); //connects to firebase collection
           adapterSearch.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#firebaseui-for-cloud-firestore) to be able to use the class `FirestoreRecyclerOptions`, add the following dependencies in the `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'
```

then you can do following:

```
querySearch = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
               .collection("App").document(" " + userID).collection("reminders")
               .startAt("title", newText)
               .endAt("title", newText+"\uf8ff"); 


FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ModelClass.class> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelClass.class>()
    .setQuery(querySearch, ModelClass.class)
    .build();
```

Also check the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#data-model).